# Getting child's value as a String

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Best way to explain myself is to show you a piece of code:

This is my XML file I'm parsing:

```
<module>
    <name>name1</name>
    <type>type</type>
    <content>
        <p>This is some piece of code that should be treated as a full string, even that 'p' tag, because I want to use all content inside p tag for a webview in android.
        </p>
        <h1>This is a big classy title in html</h1>
    </content>
</module>
```

As you can read in the `p` tag, basically I want to get the `<content>` tag's content and save it into a String to be treated. So at the end, I want to have a String initializated like:

`String content = "<p> This is some piece.......</p> <h1>This is....</h1>";`

This is my code that I'm using to get `<name>`, `<type>` values:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(contingut);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("module");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    Element element = (Element) node;
    if(element.getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE){
        System.out.println(getValue("name",element));
        System.out.println(getContent("content",element));
    }
}
private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    String value="";
    try {
        NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
        value=node.getNodeValue();
    } catch (Exception e){
        value=null;
    }
    return value;
}
```

So for instance, when parsing, Name is printed correctly `name1`, but `content` is returning blank.

Any idea how can I get `<content>`'s content as a String?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

```
private static String getContent(String tag, Element element) {
    String value="";
    try {
        Node nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);
        value = nodes.getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e){
        value=null;
    }
    return value;
}

Log.d("debugging",getContent("content",element));
```

And this is printing this:

`%20%20%20%20%20This%20some%20piece ....`

It seems that it's not returning the string `<p>`.

Comment: xml which you posted is not well formatted and dom parser will throw parse exception. If this is the xml which you want to parse as @AlexS suggested you may need to use SAX Parser.

Comment: @code13 my bad, it's a typo while writting it down here. It's correctly closed now.

Comment: Would it be possible to have all the tags under content inside CDATA, or should it be this way specifically?

Comment: should be this way, because xml is being sent this way by a 3rd.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán have you tried getContent function posted in my answer, because I tried with your xml and its working for me(Its same as yours getValue with just function change from getValue to getContent).

Comment: @code13 yup, even commented your answer. I've tried this code http://pastebin.com/0C04sPTr and its returning http://pastebin.com/8aCigDEy. And trying your code: http://pastebin.com/M8Eb7MBi its returning: http://pastebin.com/PWFceKXJ

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán I think you have to reconstruct the string yourself. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [getTextContent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) doesn't return any markup I think it won't be possible using any of the Node-methods.

The only way I see (if you want to use DocumentBuilder) is, that you **write some code to rebuild the string out of the nodelists** (iterate through nodes and node-attributes).

As a small sketch on what I mean: (only javalike pseudocode)

```
string rebuild(NodeList nodeList) {
    string result = "";
    for (Node n : nodeList) {
        result += "<" + node.getNodeName() + " ";
        NamedNodeMap aMap = node.getAttributes();
        if (aMap != null) {
            int aMapLength = aMap.getLength();
            for (int i=0; i<aMapLength; ++i) {
                Node a = aMap.item(i);
                result += a.getNodeName() + "=" + a.getValue() + " ";
            }
        }
        NodeList nList = node.getChildNodes();
        if (nList == null) {
            result += "/>";
        } else {
            result += ">";
            result += rebuild(nList);
            result += "</" + node.getNodeName() + ">";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could also create a xsd file and to use xjc (JAXB) to create Java-classes. There are a lot of good tutorials out their on how to do this (depending on your IDE).
Then you could have everything marshaled/ unmarshaled by JAXB as you like.

Another way would be that you implement your own [SaxHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) instead and use SAXParser and SAXParserFactory, which will be quite some work.

Comment: my parser is already 800'ish lines long, cant handle a big implementation change by now...

Comment: 800 lines are quite a bit, but a change to JAXB shouldn't be to much trouble, and you would have the benefit of a XSD-File (validating) and easy adoption to new elements...

Comment: Will think about it if I feel much limitated, but by now it's working kinda decently. By the way, I've edited my code, managed to get the value, but it's somehow ignoring / changing `<p>`tags for space html code. Check it out =)

Comment: [getTextContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) doesn't contain any markups and is not normalized.

Comment: That's it. I think this is the best way to achieve this. As we found out getTextContent is removing the tags. So I though a way of doing this, somehow like you're doing it. I decode '<', '>' symbols to the corresponding html &321;(whatever), then when I render that text, I code it again to '<', after that, it should render normally in a html view.

Comment: OK. I thought you mustn't change the XML-structure?! I don't understand why you will not simply be using CDATA, if you can alter the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use **getTextContent**() instead of **getValue**() function. Following is an example(same as yours getValue function).

```
private static String getContent(String tag, Element element) {
    String value="";
    try {
        NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
        value=node.getTextContent(); // notice getTextContent()
    } catch (Exception e){
        value=null;
    }
    return value;
}
```

It will work with well formatted xml

```
<module>
    <name>name1</name>
    <type>type</type>
    <content>
        <p>This is some piece of code that should be treated as a full string, even that 'p' tag, because I want to use all content inside p tag for a webview in android.
        </p>
        <h1>This is a big classy title in html</h1>
     </content>
</module>
```

Comment: this is returning blank. Even though check out my `getContent` function I've put in the edit of my main question. Looks kinda like yours but mine is returning content, but weird formatted.